# Oracle SQL CMD Line

Tags: oracle, cmd, line, sqlplus

Whenever I perform select statements in the command line tool it doesn't use all of the space.

I've modified buffer size and window size and it just doesn't work.

Here is the screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sqlplus, execute this:

```
SET LINESIZE 1500
```

Answer (score 1):

sqlplus does not automatically adjust its output width to fit your terminal window width. You need to change the width with something like `set linesize 120`

You might want to peruse the [SQL*Plus](http://www.oracle.com/technology/docs/tech/sql_plus/index.html) documentation for more information on controlling output format.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [Oracle Forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1042514):

If you want to make this permanent, in your DB/Oracle client directory look for the file **glogin.sql** in **$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin** and add this line:

```
SET LINESIZE 9999;
```

Now it will be set whenever you login into SQL Plus.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your windows console properties alone won't help.
You need to tell oracle's sqlplus engine to put output in your perferred manner. This is done by `Set` options

example:

```
SET LIN 300
```

Will use 300 columns per line